# Specific Terms and Conditions based on Product Selection

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, products, selection, terms-and-conditions, billing-agreements

Is there a way of only showing SPECIFIC Terms and Conditions during the checkout process only if SPECIFIC products are in the basket?

I am currently using Bartosz Górski's Conditional Agreements module.
https://github.com/bgorski/conditionalagreements

However, this module shows ALL terms and conditions if specific products are in the basket. If none of the relevent products are in the basket, then NONE of the terms and conditions are shown. 
(It works by products having a 'show agreements' attribute)

What I really want is something like this:

Basket Contains Product A => Show Agreement A only
Basket Contains Product B => Show Agreement B only
Basket Contains Products A & B => Show Agreement A and Agreement B

Rather than what I have with the current module

Basket Contains Product A => Show Agreement A and B
Basket Contains Product B => Show Agreement A and B
Basket Contains Products A & B => Show Agreement A and B

Any ideas where I can go with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used product custom options as a workaround.  Make a required checkbox outlining your terms before they can add to cart.  You can even use an extension to have downloadable PDF, etc for your option.

Comment: Not a bad workaround. However, don't these custom options show on the invoice? (I'd rather they didn't)

Comment: Depending if you need custom options for other item uses, you could just comment out the rendering of the options on the PDF.